# finding date in sql

Tags: sql-server

i need a query to find the date based on year, month, day of the week and weekday number. Say for example, if the question is to find the date of 2nd Sunday of January 2010, the answer should be '2010-01-10'.

Inputs are

```
Yr   | Mon | Dy  | Dyno
-----------------------
2010 | Jan | Sun | 2
2005 | Jan | Mon | 3
1995 | Feb | Sun | 1
2000 | Feb | Wed | 4
1982 | Mar | Tue | 2
2010 | Mar | Tue | 8
```

Dyno states dayno

Comment: What does the last line of inputs mean? You want the 8th Tuesday of March 2010? Clearly there wasn't one.

Comment: This looks like it probably does roughly what you need though http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2009/06/17/How-to-get-the-Nth-weekday-of-a-month.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The easiest answer to many date-related questions in SQL is to [create a calendar table](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2010/07/19/calendar-table-and-datetime-functions.aspx). In your case, if you create a table with the columns you've already shown, and an extra one with the `DATETIME` value that you want (call it `BaseDate`), you can get the value you need with a simple query:

```
select BaseDate
from dbo.Calendar
where Yr = 2010 and Mon = 'Jan' and Dy = 'Sunday' and Dyno = 2
```

Of course, your calendar table can have 10, 20 or more columns, depending on what values you find useful for your queries.

Comment: Hi martin, If the Date does not exist,'Invalid Date' should be displayed.